# qooxdoo: how to choose different scenarios in "apply" method, depending on the invocation context?

Tags: qooxdoo

Imagine a karaoke player / keyframe animation system / etc. written in qooxdoo. A Player object will have a property to reflect current position. The property will be bound to some GUI control, say slider, so that the user can jump to an arbitrary position. In the same time, position will be gradually updated by the playback mechanism when playing.

The problem is, different logic should be applied in these two cases.

1) If the "position" property is set from outside (for example, the user has clicked a slider), some complex logic applies: we should recompute active verse/line/syllable/pair of keyframes (possibly using binary search) and activate it;
2) If the property has been updated by an iteration of playback mechanism, the logic is very simple: we should only check if the boundary of the next object has been crossed, and advance to it.

In both cases the standard logic (instance check and firing change event) should be invoked. I've been thinking about either bypassing complex "apply" method by setting $$user_position variable directly, or analyzing current call stack and taking different paths depending on that, but both methods seem to be dirty hacks. That's why I'll be thankful for any recommendations on how to implement the said in qooxdoo the Right™ Way®.

Answer (score 2):

I think a common pattern for such a situation is not to burden the property itself with too much functionality (meaning: its apply method). Rather, keep the property rather simple and use it just to record the current position. Then devise methods like 'goto' and 'next' that both update the position property, albeit with different algorithms, as you wrote.